# Error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment what to do

Tags: c++, qt

i get this error 'lvalue required as left operand of assignment' when a run a same piece of code in QT on a windows machine but works fine when i use a linux machine.

```
unsigned int width = Width, height = Height, slice = Slice;

typedef boost::multi_array<std::complex<double>,3> IMAGE;
typedef IMAGE::index im;
IMAGE Image(boost::extents[slice][height][width]);

for (im i = 0; i < slice; i++)
{
    for (im j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        for (im k = 0; k < width; k++)
        {
            Image[i][j][k].real() = image[i][j][k];
            Image[i][j][k].imag() = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

is the error because of a difference in compiler? or is there something i am missing? the linux version has a GCC compiler and the windows version uses MINGW 32 bit

Comment: What do `real()` and `imag()` return?

Comment: @serpentor is right. They return `double`, not `double &`. Use `Image[i][j][k].real(image[i][j][k]);` instead.

Comment: @Gill Bates real() returns the real part of image and imag() returns the imaginary part in image. Assuming that image has complex values.

Answer (score 5):

`real()` and `imag()` returning assignable references was a non-standard extension for libstdc++ ([source](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51013)). If you set `-std=c++1y` in g++, you'll get the same error.

For changing the values you should be using the 'setter' version instead:

```
Image[i][j][k].real(image[i][j][k]);
Image[i][j][k].imag(0);
```

Comment: incase image[i][j][k] is a complex image with both real and imaginary parts then how do i differentiate that?