# Complex number assignment no longer seems to work

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile some older code and i keep getting:

```
../include/timeobject.h: In member function ‘void timeobject::initialize()’:
../include/timeobject.h:24:17: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    real(f[i]) = 0.;
                 ^~
../include/timeobject.h:25:17: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    imag(f[i]) = 0.;
                 ^~
../include/timeobject.h: In member function ‘void timeobject::integrateRK4()’:
../include/timeobject.h:57:32: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    real(v[ktime])=real(f[ktime]);
```

This code used to compile without issues. All the compile errors are like this and all only appear on lines where there is some assignment to real/imaginary part of a complex variable.

What am I forgetting? (the program is being compiled with openmpi version:

```
mpicxx --version
g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
```

Comment: This might help: https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1258753

Comment: *"This code used to compile without issues"* - This is interesting, since it certainly wasn't doing what was intended.  Proof that compilers have gotten better at catching common mistakes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264539/error-lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment-what-to-do) . See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real

Comment: Simply adding -std=c++98 resolved the issue immediately. @0x5453 I am not sure what you mean, but this seems to be due to change in specification in c++.